# How to rotate the z label in 3D plots

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

Let's take the following simple and funny case

```
S0 = ParametricPlot3D[{t*Sin[t], t*Cos[t], t}, {t, -100, 100}, 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "a very long label"}, ImageSize -> 550]
```

which gives this

[image: plot]

We see, that the label of the z axes is printed horizontally by default, thus wasting a lot of space. In two-dimensional plots however, this can be easily fixed with the option `RotateLabel -> False`. Is there something similar for three-dimensional plots for rotating and printing vertically the z label?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are aware of `Rotate["a very long label", 90 Degree]` right?

Comment: @Öskå I am now! thanks.

Comment: "Rotate" or ["Reverse"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/psDfG.png)?

Comment: @cormullion I meant Rotate. Thanks for the correction! I also updated my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think using 2D rotation is simplest solution:

```
S0 = ParametricPlot3D[{t*Sin[t], t*Cos[t], t}, {t, -100, 100},
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", Rotate["a very long label", 
1.7]},ImageSize -> 550]
```

Comment: For better readability of the label you should rotate it by Pi/2.